# Error H-10 on deploying my Rails App on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, puma

I am having issues understanding the logs provided by Heroku regarding the crash of my application..

Can someone help me understand the error message please ?

For more information the app is a simple one page app.

Enclosed a picture of the logs [image: Logs]

EDIT : Gemfile = >[image]

Comment: Can you provide your `Gemfile` please? Maybe puma doesn't installed in production env. Your heroku app can't find `puma` executable

Comment: @Xiting sure it is done

Comment: Can you also share `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Reference: https://www.alanvardy.com/posts/38 probably you need to allow track tmp/pids folder for git, or create it manually in heroku instance `touch tmp/pids`

Comment: @Xiting Thanks a lot for this ! It works now, indeed the pids file was in the gitignore. 
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: alanvardy.com/posts/38

Probably you need to allow track tmp/pids folder for git, or create it manually in heroku instance:
`touch tmp/pids`